# Comparar el dato de un case con un campo en SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

quisiera ver la forma de comparar el resultado de un case con un campo

algo asi

```
SELECT

CASE
WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
END AS 'TIPO DE CAMBIO',

CASE 

WHEN 'dato de case 1' > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
WHEN 'dato de case 1' <= sh1.min_unit_price THEN 'NO EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
END AS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS',
```

Answer (score 1):

En el contexto de una consulta a una tabla:

#### (1) Copias la lógica del primer `CASE` en el segundo

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
             WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
        END AS 'TIPO DE CAMBIO',

        CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
                        WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price    
                  END) > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
    END AS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS'

    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
```

#### (2) Usas una subconsulta o una [`CTE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para "materializar" la columna calculada

```
SELECT  [TIPO DE CAMBIO], 
        CASE WHEN [TIPO DE CAMBIO] > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO' END AS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS'
        FROM ( 
        SELECT  CASE WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
                     WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
                END AS 'TIPO DE CAMBIO'
            FROM ..
            WHERE .. 
    ) T
```

Ahora, como sugerencia, te sería mucho más simple, si en vez de tener una variable única `@TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD` tuvieras una tabla temporal con la moneda y tipo de cambio y las cotizaciones para las monedas que correspondan, en tu caso la moneda local tendría `cotizacion = 1`, por ejemplo:

```
-- Tabla temporal, o bien podría ser física si lo necesitamos
DECLARE @Cotizaciones TABLE (
    Currency_Code VARCHAR(15),
    Cotizacion NUMERIC(15,6)
)
-- Insertamos los valores
INSERT INTO @Cotizaciones(Currency_Code, Cotizacion) VALUES('USD',  @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD)
INSERT INTO @Cotizaciones(Currency_Code, Cotizacion) VALUES('MXN',  1)

-- Los aprovechamos en una consulta
SELECT  A2.Unit_Price * C.Cotizacion  AS 'TIPO DE CAMBIO',
        CASE WHEN (A2.Unit_Price * C.Cotizacion) > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO' END AAS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS'
    FROM TuTabla A1
    ...
    INNER JOIN @Cotizaciones C
        ON A1.Currency_Code = C.Currency_Code
```

Como puedes ver, nos sacamos de encima el `CASE` y todo se reduce a una multiplicación: `(A2.Unit_Price * C.Cotizacion)`

Answer (score 0):

```
--Primero necesitamos la variable a jugar:
@precioUnitario decimal(8,2)
--Segundo, hay que definir el valor de dicha variable
SET @precioUnitario =   
    CASE 
      WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'USD' THEN A2.Unit_Price * @TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_USD
      WHEN A1.Currency_Code = 'MXN' THEN A2.Unit_Price
    END 

CASE 
--Tercer, usar esa variable previamente definida.
WHEN @precioUnitario > sh1.min_unit_price  THEN 'EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
WHEN @precioUnitario <= sh1.min_unit_price THEN 'NO EXISTE UN MEJOR PRECIO'
END AS 'ANALISIS DE DATOS',
```